# Tracking clicks in a website

Tags: python, google-analytics

I have a website containing some information and links in the form of buttons and url. I am tracking data of that website using Google Analytics. So is there any way I can track the clicks or from where can I collect information about all the clicks made in the website? I have used Python to push the data to MySQL tracked by GA.

Answer (score 0):

You can use event-tracking. You just have to add `ga('send', 'event', [eventCategory], [eventAction], [eventLabel], [eventValue], [fieldsObject]);` to every link/button on your page: https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/analyticsjs/events